# how to find command-mode equivalent of normal-mode command?

Tags: vim

I frequently find myself wondering what the command-mode version of a normal-mode command is, usually to use it in a g/// expression.  For instance, the equivalent of "J" is "join", and the equivalent of "dd" is "d" (or at least it seems like it).  Is there a general way of figuring this out - a help function I'm missing, or just a list somewhere?

(Right now I'm looking for a command-mode equivalent of gq, but this happens often enough that a general solution would be better.)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a lazy solution would be to simply use `:normal`, for example `:g/^.\+$/normal gqap` to format all paragraphs.

Comment: @glts I wasn't aware of `:normal`, thanks! That solves most of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not functions for all the commands (most commands are pretty simple and some even involve switching to other modes).

The `:join` command is really an exception. To use normal mode commands, just use

```
:normal J
```

If you want to write a script, use `:normal!`, because you should not trust the vimrc's out there.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of `:normal` - that's clearly the underlying problem I was attempting to solve the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best help pages in vim is index.txt, accessed via `:help index`.  It's so useful I bind it to `<F1>`.  It has sections showing all the commands and keystrokes available in each mode.  You can open it up and search to your heart's content, and of course it's all crosslinked.

If you want to see all the ways you can join lines, open it up and do `/join` to find all occurrences.